# Fresh Install MacOS Maverick on a Mac 8,1 (2008)

Tags: mac, osx-mavericks, maverick

Recently the brother offers me an iMac (8.1 - 2008- with Maverick OS), which he hasn't used in a long time. I wanted to set it up for my kids so i erased all the data from the HDD using the disk utility. Now i'm having trouble to download and reinstall the MacOS using the OS utilities when i try to login with my apple id It keeps appering a message telling that the password is wrong and to recover it. I checked and double checked and The password is correct. Facing this problem i tried to download Maverick DMG file  and flash in to USB with Transmac on windows PC, coverted to GBT but im getting the prohibitory symbol. Is the any other way to install the Maverick OS using a Flash Drive?

iMac specs:
Model: iMac 8,1
Intel Core 2 duo - 2.66 Ghz
Previous OS Maverick 10.9.5

Best regards

Comment: You have what could be called a 'cusp' machine there. It's tough to get an 08 to boot from USB [even if you are using a proven USB] Your issue is going to be compounded by the fact that you need to use Safari to download the official installers without the out-of-date issues the older ones all have. You can get El Capitan onto that Mac, but I'm not sure how you're going to get started, unless you can get hold of a Lion CD [eBay etc] to do the first install. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275 which has a lot of information on this.

Comment: The 'wrong password' etc is all part of this issue. The old Macs don't understand the newer protocols, the installer it tries to access is out of date, so it fails. If you have no other recourse [friend with a Mac & CD burner etc] then an Apple Store should do it for you, for free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First I will try by using a friends mac and then apple store.